# Electron allows `require('path')` in renderer even when `nodeIntegration` is set to `false`

Tags: electron

My understanding is that setting `nodeIntegration` to `false` will block access to Node modules in the renderer process. But I'm able to do `require('path')` in spite of having `nodeIntegration` set to `false`.

Is my understanding not correct?

If my understanding is correct but `path` is given an exception, I wonder if there are other modules given the same exception?

Here's my `BrowserWindow` options

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      // The below configurations are set to achieve the maximum
      // security possible in Electron
      contextIsolation: true,
      webSecurity: true,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
      nodeIntegration: false,
      nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: false,
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: false,
      allowRunningInsecureContent: false,
      sandbox: true,

      preload: join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },

    center: true,
    title: "Orange",
    minWidth: 800,
    minHeight: 600,
  });
```

Comment: Can you also post your `BrowserWindow` options? Just to check that you're setting `nodeIntegration` inside `webPreferences`.

Comment: @Joshua I've updated the post to add the `BrowserWindow` options

Comment: Thanks Safi, everything looks good with that. Are you saying that you are still able to `require('path')` inside your preload script, or inside your page?

Comment: @Joshua I'm able to do `import path from 'path'` in one of the files that make up `app.js` which is referenced in `index.html` (I'm building with webpack by the way)